# How to translate "(Ямщик) Качает буйной головой" into English?

Tags: грамматика, словоупотребление

This is a phrase in the lyrics of the Russian folk song "Вот мчится тройка почтовая".  Although there are many web sites about this song in English, they have often translated it by something like "(The coachman) swings his head wildly".  Grammatically speaking, however, the "буйный" is an adjective to describe the noun "голова" rather than an adverb to qualify the verb "качать".  How to translate this phrase into English accurately?

Answer (score 6):

You are correct about the grammar. However, I think "буйный" is one of those words which are difficult to translate, especially in one word (like "грозный" in "Иван Грозный").

The best place to look for the meaning in this case is Dal's dictionary, which [says](http://slovari.yandex.ru/~%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8/%D0%A2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C%20%D0%94%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8F/%D0%91%D0%A3%D0%99%D0%9D%D0%AB%D0%99/):

> Буйная голова, беспокойная; в сказках и песнях горькая, горемычная,
>   бесприютная.

If I had to translate the phrase as a lyrics line, I would go for something like "The coachman shakes his restless head". "Wild" is not wrong as such (if used as an adjective), but hard to understand without the necessary background.

Answer (score 2):

You answered your own question, really. "Буйный" can be translated as "wild", so in this case it would be not "swings head wildly" but "swings his wild head".

On a side note, "swings" isn't really appropriate in this case, proper word would be "shakes his head", for example, "shake one's head in disbelief".

Though, I'm going off of the most regular usages of these phrases. The original sentence in its full context implies the stage-coachman is preoccupied with thoughts of the woman he loves.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I think you are right from a grammatical viewpoint.  But there are few web sites that translate this phrase by something like "shakes his wild head".  Moreover, I cannot imagine what a “буйная голова” is like.  I hope you or someone will explain it.